# How can we create Android Service which sends notification every 30 seconds without having activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

***Hi Friend,***

*I could not run an Android service in my Device. It works well in the Emulator.*
Here is my sample code: Please review the code .

***MyScheduleReceiver.java:***

```
    package com.smpt.wi_ficonnector;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Restart service every 30 seconds
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    //
    // Fetch every 30 seconds
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

    // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    // REPEAT_TIME, pending);

}
}
```

***MyService.java:***

This class calls wifiservice class. This starts the service.

```
    package com.smpt.wi_ficonnector;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;

    public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

***MyStartServiceReceiver.java:***

This class calls my service class. This service class will show notification to the user.

```
    package com.smpt.wi_ficonnector;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, WifiService.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
}
```

***WifiService.java:***

This class used to check for wifi connection and send notification of every 30 seconds.

package com.smpt.wi_ficonnector;

```
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Binder;
    import android.os.IBinder;

    public class WifiService extends Service {

private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean networkStatus = haveNetworkConnection();
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    Notification not;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(networkStatus == true || netInfo.isConnected() == true){
         not = new Notification(R.drawable.on, "Wi-Fi Connector", System.currentTimeMillis());
    } else {
         not = new Notification(R.drawable.off, "Wi-Fi is not connector", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);        
    not.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    if(networkStatus == true || netInfo.isConnected() == true){
        not.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Wi-Fi Connector" , "Wi-Fi is connected. You can download data.", contentIntent);
    } else {
        not.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Wi-Fi Connector" , "Wi-Fi is not connected. You can not download data.", contentIntent);
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, not);

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    WifiService getService() {
        return WifiService.this;
    }
}

private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml:***

This manifest file tells the android application to run the service in background. And It will not use any activity.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smpt.wi_ficonnector"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--activity
        android:name="com.smpt.wi_ficonnector.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-->

    <service
        android:name=".WifiService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/service_name" >
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="MyService"
        android:process=":meinprocess"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/service_name" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
    </receiver>

</application>
```

**My code is working fine in the emulator. But it is not working in the real device. Please help me out to find the problem.**

Comment: And the error is....?

Comment: No, It is not showing any error in the logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android 3.1 you will not receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent unless the user has run the application at least once. Since you've got no Activities in your manifest, there is no way for the user to run your application. This will not work on devices running Android 3.1 or later.

See "Launch controls on stopped applications" at http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html